TypeError: Cannot read property 'allowFontScaling' of undefined, js engine: hermes
I am experiencing the following error after upgrading the expo sdk version to 51.
The errors are

TypeError: Cannot read property 'allowFontScaling' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:



Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

enter image description here
So I wrote the code on the App.js and it's not working at all. What should I do?
`
Text.defaultProps = {
  ...(Text.defaultProps || {}),
  allowFontScaling: false,
};
TextInput.defaultProps = {
  ...(TextInput.defaultProps || {}),
  allowFontScaling: false,
};

enter image description here

I have exactly the same error after upgrading to sdk 51. Hope someone can help.

did you find a solution ?

I had the same issue. For me it was a dependency issue. One of the libraries I was using is not handling 'allowFontScaling' correctly. In order to figure out which library is causing the issue, I did the following:

First, check the error log to see which component is the problem child
(see screenshot)

My log is showing some issue with "react-native-button"


Note: If you are using this library in your app then simply update it to the latest version, uninstall it, or patch it and you're done 
In my case, I am not using this component at all in my app, so it likely means that one of my dependencies is using "react-native-button" as a sub-dependency. So you move onto the next step

run the following:



yarn why react-native-button



This will tell you which library is using the problem code (for me it was react-native-star-rating).


info Reasons this module exists
   - "react-native-star-rating" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "react-native-star-rating#react-native-button"




At this point, you can either update the react-native-star-rating library version, create a patch, or in my case just delete it and use something else because it hasn't been updated in over 7 years


Came here for the same issue with the same library. I ended up going with react-native-star-rating-widget and it is a great alternative!
